# Magento Site starts showing fatal error message without any code changes on server

Tags: php, magento

We have inherited a magento (CE 1.8.1.0) installation that is showing the following error on a Friday morning on opening the product page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setType() on a non-object in /data/www.walls.pk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Collection.php on line 54

There have been no changes to the code on the server that was running fine for the last 6 months.

Can there be a server related or configuration related change (i am thinking from the hosting company) or a version upgrade that causes such an issue ?

Comment: Show the line of code

Answer (score 0):

Your core eav entity model is unable to instantiate.

```
$entityTypeId = (int)Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)->getTypeId();
```

Assuming you have a file that exists in:

> app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity.php

Clear all caches and delete any cache folders in

> root/var/

Run Magento's database fix utility.

Post your

> root/var/log/exception.log

and

> system.log

contents ( Enable logs if they're empty ).

Check your apache logs for detailed info.